# How do I add to PATH a directory with colon (":") in it?

Tags: linux, directory, environment-variables, path

[Here](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Payloads/File-Names) I found the file with `..:;` name. `mkdir '..:;'` worked fine. But in PATH directory names are split by `:`. How to add this directory to PATH?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29213487/2072269

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The POSIX standard explicitly mentions that it's impossible to use directories with `:` in their names in the `PATH` variable's value.

See the entry about the `PATH` environment variable in the section entitled [Other Environment Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03):

> Since `<colon>` is a separator in this context, directory names that might be used in `PATH` should not include a `<colon>` character.

---

In the `zsh` shell, you would be able to add the directory to your search path and have it work as expected by modifying your `path` array variable (which is *tied to* `PATH`):

```bash
path+=( '/some/path/..:;' )
```

or to add the entry first rather than last:

```bash
path=( '/some/path/..:;' $path )
```

However, after doing this, modifying the shell's search path using `PATH` rather than via the `path` array will cause the `..:;` entry to be split on the `:`.  Also, note that although the modified path may work in the `zsh` shell, it is unlikely to work as expected in another shell or in an application started from that shell.

Comment: To prepend an element to an array in zsh, you can also do: `path[1,0]=(element)`

Comment: The `$path` trick seems to also work in `tcsh` (the `$PATH` tied to `$path` was borrowed from csh), not in `fish` where `$PATH` is some sort of magic array. `PATH=(dir:with:colon)` seems to work in `yash` as well.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29213487/12231187), it is impossible because `$PATH` is not interpreted by the shell, but by  `execvp` which doesn't provide for escaping the separator character.

Comment: I don't expect many shells will use `execvp()` from the libc as they'll likely want to construct the `envp[]` array passed as the 3rd argument to `execve()` by themselves (based on the shell variables marked for export).